# How to get convert into date value

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to convert text value into date

```
Textbox1 column value = 31/12/2009 (dd/MM/yyyy)
```

Tried

```
Cdate(textbox1.text)
```

The above code is not working.

I want to get a date like this '31 Dec 2009'

How to write a code for getting this format.

Need vb.net code help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

> Converts the specified string
>   representation of a date and time to
>   its DateTime equivalent using the
>   specified array of formats,
>   culture-specific format information,
>   and style. The format of the string
>   representation must match at least one
>   of the specified formats exactly. The
>   method returns a value that indicates
>   whether the conversion succeeded.

This will allow you to parse the string into a DateTime. You can then use ToString to format the date as you wish.

Have a look at [DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Help / Search in the IDE and then search for "datetime string format".